# How to save user input into variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id= "playerNames" class="playerInfo">
            <form name="form1" method="post" action="http://examples.funwebdev.com/process.php" id="newGame">
                <p id= "userInput">
                    <label>Player 1 name: </label></br><input type="text" name="p1" id="nameOne" value="" required></input></br>
                    <label>Player 2 name: </label></br><input type="text" name="p2" id="nameTwo" required></input> <input id="submit" type="submit" value="New Game"/>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
```

And the following javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("jQuery is ready to use...");
    $("#newGame").on("submit", newGameListener);
});

function setUpUsers(){
    var player_One = document.getElementById("nameOne").value;
    var player_Two = document.getElementById("nameTwo").value;
    document.getElementById("pTurns").innerHTML = (+nameTwo+ ", its your turn");
    document.getElementById("pScores").innerHTML = (+nameOne+ ": 50pts </br>" (+nameTwo+ ": 50pts </br>"
}

function newGameListener(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUpUsers();
}
```

I am trying to append these two variables (nameOne, nameTwo) within p elements.  However when this code is run I get NaN (Not a Number) Instead of the user input as a string.  Not sure how I should go about achieving this!

Comment: Unclosed parenthesis syntax errors at `(+nameOne+ ": 50pts </br>" (+nameTwo+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vohuman and @guest271314 answered about your problem(`NaN`) but you have several syntax error in your HTML and javascript, however I fixed that I optimized your javascript.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/2e7ct0th/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("jQuery is ready to use...");
  $("#newGame").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var player_One = $('#nameOne').val();
    var player_Two = $('#nameTwo').val();
    $('#pTurns').html(player_One + ", its your turn");
    $('#pScores').html(player_One + ": 50pts </br>" + player_Two + ": 50pts </br>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="playerNames" class="playerInfo">
  <form name="form1" method="post" id="newGame">
    <p id="userInput">
      <label>Player 1 name:</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="p1" id="nameOne" value="" required />
      <br />
      <label>Player 2 name:</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="p2" id="nameTwo" required />
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="New Game" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>

<p id="pTurns"></p>
<p id="pScores"></p>
```

Comment: Also very bad idea to name or use id=submit. Lastly he should use $("#newGame").on("submit" instead of the click event

Comment: @lewisfurlan-lowry you should give upvote to Vohuman because I answered half of your question.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are converting a DOM element to a number. The result will be, em.., `NaN`.  What you want is the value of the element. You can get the value by reading the `.value` property.

```
document.getElementById("pTurns").innerHTML = (+nameTwo.value + ", its your turn");
```

However, since you want to concatenate the value with a string there is no need to use `+` operator.

Also note that should not rely on the global variables (some browsers like Chrome creates global variables that refer to elements that have the corresponding IDs) for accessing the elements, it's fragile and may fail miserably. Yes, [it has been standardized by HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object), but in my opinion it's a *bad* practice. Use the `document.getElementById` method for selecting the elements by their id.

Comment: Noticed that `nameTwo`, `nameOne` not appear defined at `js` at Question ?

Comment: @lewisfurlan-lowry Are you still using  the `+` operator?  Try with removing it. If the user input is not a number  then the  operator  returns `NaN`.